# Keep values in table using php without using session or cookies

Tags: php, html, arrays, netbeans

I have this assignment and i have been working on it all weekend.

Here is the scope of the assignment,

1. Products are stored in a multidimensional array
2. Display the products in a table
3. Update the product quantity using '+' and '-' button
4. If quantity > 0, display a '-' button to update quantity as required.
5. Checkout button to display -- quantities > 0, total prices of products whose quantities are greater than 0.

I am stuck at updating the table because each time i click on a different '+' button on the table, the other table rows reverse back to their original state and i don't want that. I want their values to remain after clicking on another '+' button on the table.

- I updated product 1 quantity then
- I updated product 2 quantity and the updated quantity and subtotal price in product 1 is set back to its initial array values.

The logic i want to use is "update whole multidimensional array after each click on various '+' and '-' button and display the 'updated' array back into the table. But I have problem implementing this logic or is their another logic to go about this??

Here is my code so far for the assignment.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        // put your code here
        $ShowForm = True;
        $items = array(
            "Product 1" => array
                (
                "Qty" => 0,
                "Item" => "Product 1",
                "Unit Price" => 5,
                "Subtotal" => 0
            ),
            "Product 2" => array
                (
                "Qty" => 0,
                "Item" => "Product 2",
                "Unit Price" => 2.3,
                "Subtotal" => 0
            ),
            "Product 3" => array
                (
                "Qty" => 0,
                "Item" => "Product 3",
                "Unit Price" => 3.54,
                "Subtotal" => 0
            ),
            "Product 4" => array
                (
                "Qty" => 0,
                "Item" => "Product 4",
                "Unit Price" => 1.67,
                "Subtotal" => 0
            ),
            "Product 5" => array
                (
                "Qty" => 0,
                "Item" => "Product 5",
                "Unit Price" => 3.4,
                "Subtotal" => 0
            )
        );
            ?>
            <h3>Update the products below as required.<br>Then you can click on the checkout button below.</h3>
            <form method="POST" action= "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" > 
                <?php
                echo '<table border = 1 id=\'products\'>';
                echo '<th>Qty</th>';
                echo '<th>Item</th>';
                echo '<th>Unit Price</th>';
                echo '<th>Subtotal</th>';

                $i = count($items);
                foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
                    echo'<tr class=\'' . $key . '\'>';
                    $i--;

                    if ($key === "Product 1") {
                        $product1 = array();
                        foreach ($value as $dim => &$num) {
                            if ($dim === "Qty") {
                                echo '<td><input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add' . $i . '\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $num;
                                if (ISSET($_POST['add4'])) {
                                    $newQty = ($_POST['qty4']) + 1;
                                    echo $newQty;
                                    //echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add'.$i.'\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$newQty;
                                    echo '<input type=\'hidden\' value=\'' . $newQty . '\' name=\'qty4\'>';
                                    echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'-\' name=\'remove4\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
                                    $value['Subtotal'] = $newQty * $value['Unit Price'];
                                    $value['Qty'] = $newQty;
                                }
                                if (ISSET($_POST['remove4'])) {
                                    $newQty = ($_POST['qty4']) - 1;
                                    echo $newQty;
                                    //echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add'.$i.'\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$newQty;
                                    echo '<input type=\'hidden\' value=\'' . $newQty . '\' name=\'qty4\'>';
                                    $value['Subtotal'] = $newQty * $value['Unit Price'];
                                    if ($newQty > 0) {
                                        echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'-\' name=\'remove4\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
                                    }
                                }
                            } elseif ($dim === "Subtotal") { 
                                echo '<td>'.$value['Subtotal'].'</td>';// . '</td>';
                            }else {

                                echo '<td>' . $num . '</td>';
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    if ($key === "Product 2") {
                        foreach ($value as $dim => &$num) {


                            if ($dim === "Qty") {
                                echo '<td><input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add' . $i . '\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $num;
                                if (ISSET($_POST['add3'])) {
                                    $newQty = ($_POST['qty3']) + 1;
                                    echo $newQty;
                                    //echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add'.$i.'\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$newQty;
                                    echo '<input type=\'hidden\' value=\'' . $newQty . '\' name=\'qty3\'>';
                                    echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'-\' name=\'remove3\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
                                    $value['Subtotal'] = $newQty * $value['Unit Price'];
                                    $value['Qty'] = $newQty;        
                                }
                             if (ISSET($_POST['remove3'])) {
                                    $newQty = ($_POST['qty3']) - 1;
                                    echo $newQty;
                                    //echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add'.$i.'\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$newQty;
                                    echo '<input type=\'hidden\' value=\'' . $newQty . '\' name=\'qty3\'>';
                                    $value['Subtotal'] = $newQty * $value['Unit Price'];
                                    if ($newQty > 0) {
                                        echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'-\' name=\'remove3\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
                                    }

                                    //
                                }

                            }elseif ($dim === "Subtotal") { 
                                echo '<td>'.$value['Subtotal'].'</td>';// . '</td>';
                            }else {
                                echo '<td>' . $num . '</td>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($key === "Product 3") {
                        foreach ($value as $dim => $num) {
                            if ($dim === "Qty") {
                                echo '<td><input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add' . $i . '\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $num;
                                if (ISSET($_POST['add2'])) {
                                    $newQty = ($_POST['qty2']) + 1;
                                    echo $newQty;

                                    //echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add'.$i.'\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$newQty;
                                    echo '<input type=\'hidden\' value=\'' . $newQty . '\' name=\'qty2\'>';
                                    echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'-\' name=\'remove2\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
                                    $value['Subtotal'] = $newQty * $value['Unit Price'];
                                }

                                if (ISSET($_POST['remove2'])) {
                                    $newQty = ($_POST['qty2']) - 1;
                                    echo $newQty;
                                    //echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add'.$i.'\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$newQty;
                                    echo '<input type=\'hidden\' value=\'' . $newQty . '\' name=\'qty2\'>';
                                    $value['Subtotal'] = $newQty * $value['Unit Price'];
                                    if ($newQty > 0) {
                                        echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'-\' name=\'remove2\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
                                    }
                                }
                            } elseif ($dim === "Subtotal") { 
                                echo '<td>'.$value['Subtotal'].'</td>';// . '</td>';
                            }else {
                                echo '<td>' . $num . '</td>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($key === "Product 4") {
                        foreach ($value as $dim => $num) {
                            if ($dim === "Qty") {
                                echo '<td><input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add' . $i . '\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $num;
                                if (ISSET($_POST['add1'])) {
                                    $newQty = ($_POST['qty1']) + 1;
                                    echo $newQty;
                                    //echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add'.$i.'\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$newQty;
                                    echo '<input type=\'hidden\' value=\'' . $newQty . '\' name=\'qty1\'>';
                                    echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'-\' name=\'remove1\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
                                    $value['Subtotal'] = $newQty * $value['Unit Price'];
                                }

                                if (ISSET($_POST['remove1'])) {
                                    $newQty = ($_POST['qty1']) - 1;
                                    echo $newQty;
                                    //echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add'.$i.'\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$newQty;
                                    echo '<input type=\'hidden\' value=\'' . $newQty . '\' name=\'qty1\'>';
                                    $value['Subtotal'] = $newQty * $value['Unit Price'];
                                    if ($newQty > 0) {
                                        echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'-\' name=\'remove1\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
                                    }
                                }
                            } elseif ($dim === "Subtotal") { 
                                echo '<td>'.$value['Subtotal'].'</td>';// . '</td>';
                            }else {
                                echo '<td>' . $num . '</td>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($key === "Product 5") {
                        foreach ($value as $dim => $num) {
                            if ($dim === "Qty") {
                                echo '<td><input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add' . $i . '\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $num;
                                if (ISSET($_POST['add0'])) {
                                    $newQty = ($_POST['qty0']) + 1;
                                    echo $newQty;
                                    //echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add'.$i.'\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$newQty;
                                    echo '<input type=\'hidden\' value=\'' . $newQty . '\' name=\'qty0\'>';
                                    echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'-\' name=\'remove0\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
                                    $value['Subtotal'] = $newQty * $value['Unit Price'];
                                }
                                if (ISSET($_POST['remove0'])) {
                                    $newQty = ($_POST['qty0']) - 1;
                                    echo $newQty;
                                    //echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'+\' name=\'add'.$i.'\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$newQty;
                                    echo '<input type=\'hidden\' value=\'' . $newQty . '\' name=\'qty0\'>';
                                    $value['Subtotal'] = $newQty * $value['Unit Price'];

                                    if ($newQty > 0) {
                                        echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'-\' name=\'remove0\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
                                    }
                                }
                            } elseif ($dim === "Subtotal") { 
                                echo '<td>'.$value['Subtotal'].'</td>';// . '</td>';
                            }else {
                                echo '<td>' . $num . '</td>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    echo'</tr>';
                }
                ?>


                <p><input type="submit" value="Check Out" name="checkout">
            </form>
    <?php
if (ISSET($_POST['checkout'])) {
    echo $newQty;
}
?>
    </body>

</html>
```

P.S: I'm not asking for code handout, just explanations and code snippets (examples) is fine. Thanks.

Comment: You have made this overly complex. You should store your line items in numbered arrays instead of "Product 1". Should be just "1". Then you should array all your input names. Then your values after original display should be pulled from your form and no longer from your `$items` array

Comment: Thanks @Rasclatt. how do i get php to pull the values from the form. That's my screwed up way of saying 'update the array'. lol... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the key items that you need to work on. See what this will produce and you should get an idea of what to do. You will have to apply logic to get your other effects, but you can see how to kind of go about it.

```
$item = array(
        array
            (
            "Qty" => 0,
            "Item" => "Product 1",
            "Unit_Price" => 5,
            "Subtotal" => 0
        ),
       array
            (
            "Qty" => 0,
            "Item" => "Product 2",
            "Unit_Price" => 2.3,
            "Subtotal" => 0
        ),
        array
            (
            "Qty" => 0,
            "Item" => "Product 3",
            "Unit_Price" => 3.54,
            "Subtotal" => 0
        ),
        array
            (
            "Qty" => 0,
            "Item" => "Product 4",
            "Unit_Price" => 1.67,
            "Subtotal" => 0
        ),
        array
            (
            "Qty" => 0,
            "Item" => "Product 5",
            "Unit_Price" => 3.4,
            "Subtotal" => 0
        )
    );


    function ReOrganizeArray($array) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach($array['Qty'] as $category => $rows) {
                    $items[$i]['Qty']           =   $array['Qty'][$i];
                    $items[$i]['Item']          =   $array['Item'][$i];
                    $items[$i]['Unit_Price']    =   $array['Unit_Price'][$i];
                    $items[$i]['Subtotal']      =   $array['Subtotal'][$i];

                    $items[$i]['add']           =   (isset($array['add'][$i]))? true:false;
                    $items[$i]['remove']        =   (isset($array['remove'][$i]))? true:false;
                    $i++;
                }

            return $items;
        }

    $items  =   (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))? ReOrganizeArray($_POST):$item; ?>

            <h3>Update the products below as required.<br>Then you can click on the checkout button below.</h3>
            <form method="POST" action= "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" > 
            <table>
                <?php foreach($items as $i => $rows) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="add[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="+" /></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="remove[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="-" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Qty[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $rows['Qty']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Item[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $rows['Item']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Subtotal[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $rows['Subtotal']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Unit Price[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $rows['Unit Price']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                } ?>
            </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: wow, so their is a short version of my long code. Thanks once again... And i will study the logic for this and keep it handy.

Comment: Yes the key is to re-use as much as possible and make functions to customize your outputs of buttons and values (your addition and subtraction features).

Comment: I just thought of this: Would it be possible to save the table td into a file and have it update/rewrite to itself with each update in the table?? Just thinking aloud...

Comment: No, you should definitely stay away from writing a file for something like this. Are you running into difficulties with something?

Comment: nothing i can't handle, i hope... I was going through the php docs and came across fputcsv() and just thought it could be worthwhile to put it to the test because it also says to save the array to a file.

Comment: Yeah, I would not write to disk unless you really have to and in this instance I wouldn't

Comment: it's an assignment with these conditions and i have to try to keep to the specifications...lol.. If i don't make any progress in an hour, i'm gonna close it up and submit whatever i have implemented. I have other assignments piled up and i have used up my weekend on this :). Thanks for you help and time though. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The print_r array is giving out this output.

```
Array
    (
        [add] => Array
            (
                [0] => +
            )

        [Qty] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
                [2] => 0
                [3] => 0
                [4] => 0
            )

        [Item] => Array
            (
                [0] => Product 1
                [1] => Product 2
                [2] => Product 3
                [3] => Product 4
                [4] => Product 5
            )

        [Unit_Price] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
                [1] => 2.3
                [2] => 3.54
                [3] => 1.67
                [4] => 3.4
            )

        [Subtotal] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
                [2] => 0
                [3] => 0
                [4] => 0
            )

    )
```

Why is it doing that?? the grouping of each key into the $items array??

Comment: In order to keep your values populated, you need to save the values to an array. In order to do this, You are storing the same information as your other array only in categories. So for instance in this case, you are adding adding `+1` to the `[0]` key and since all the keys line up in each category, you can easily track what you are adding to.

Comment: So to do an add function, you get the `key` of the add which is `0` which means, you you now know to work on `$item['Qty'][0]`,`$item['Unit_Price'][0]`, `$item['Subtotal'][0]`.

Comment: To find out if something is being added, you would use `array_search("+",$item['add'])` and that will return `0` because that is the key that stores the `+` symbol. See [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) for more info.

Comment: Ok see my revision. I added a function to reorganize your array so it looks like your original one. Also, it adds in a true/false for add and remove so you can tell if something gets added or removed. One of the best things you can do is format all your data the same (each array has the same key/pairs in them. It will make your life easier.

Comment: oh,  i get it now... Thanks for the explanation. I think i got a hang of it. The only thing i missed in my long version was the update array bit. And with the sorting of the arrays in items, it would be much easier to update and change the values. I still got to ask, how did you re-arrange the items array? Or better still, what line is doing the re-arrangement? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yea, i tried to use simplehtmldom parsing to get the values from the html table into an update items array but it didn't get the values or i implemented it wrong. I will take a look at the revised code and break it down further..

Comment: The rearrangement is necessary and is auto-generated by the form. If you look at the names in your form inputs, they all have an array value like `name="Unit_Price[1]"` and `name="Qty[1]"`..etc. That's why they get regrouped but there is no way around that. You can do what I did which is put that array through a function to re-rearrange it back, OR you can just leave it and process it as is.

Comment: Ya, that was my fault regarding the your last comment. Your original array has to be identical (in structure) to the form version so that is why I put a function in there to rearrange it back to how the `$items` array originally is. The other option is to change your original array to look like the form array (in category groups instead of item groups) and just update the `foreach`.

Comment: Let me know if you are interested in how that would look. It would not have the `ReOrganizeArray($array)` function in it and your original `$items` array would look like what you pasted above. The `foreach` would also be slightly different to accommodate the different array format.

Comment: I think the reorganized array is more efficient to manipulate its values when the 'checkout' button is clicked. Thanks very much for the help, i will now have to figure out the rest on my own. Thanks once again.

Comment: Well, it's no more efficient, but it is easier to read. Cheers!